# How to set owners profile emergency information programmatically on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, contacts, sandbox

I wonder if there is anyway to set device owners medical profile info programmatically from application. I know for sandbox security one app cannot access or modify other apps data but I want to know if there is any system support i.e. open system/security dialog for setting these information from any app rather default contact app.

[image]

I want to update the information above (`iPhone -> contacts -> My card ->Show Medical ID`) from my app.

Comment: No.  Only the user can set this information.

Comment: I'm sure there are numerous reasons that legally require the user to set this information manually and disallow programmers to do it behind the scenes.

Comment: @ZGski i also think same. Just wanted to be confirmed before sending feasibility feedback to my client.